# Network graph with lights not working

Tags: graphs-and-networks

So I have

```
graph = Graph[{"Russia" \[DirectedEdge] "Crimea", 
   "Russia" \[DirectedEdge] "Donetsk", 
   "Russia" \[DirectedEdge] "Luhansk", 
   "Russia" \[DirectedEdge] "Kharkiv", 
   "Russia" \[DirectedEdge] "Sumy", 
   "Russia" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernihiv", 
   "Crimea" \[DirectedEdge] "Kherson", 
   "Donetsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Luhansk", 
   "Luhansk" \[DirectedEdge] "Donetsk", 
   "Luhansk" \[DirectedEdge] "Kharkiv", 
   "Kharkiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Luhansk", 
   "Kharkiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Sumy", "Sumy" \[DirectedEdge] "Kharkiv",
    "Sumy" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernihiv", 
   "Chernihiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Sumy", 
   "Donetsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Kharkiv", 
   "Kharkiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Donetsk", 
   "Kherson" \[DirectedEdge] "Zaporizhzhya", 
   "Zaporizhzhya" \[DirectedEdge] "Kherson", 
   "Zaporizhzhya" \[DirectedEdge] "Donetsk", 
   "Donetsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Zaporizhzhya", 
   "Kherson" \[DirectedEdge] "Dnipropetrovsk", 
   "Dnipropetrovsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Kherson", 
   "Dnipropetrovsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Zaporizhzhya", 
   "Zaporizhzhya" \[DirectedEdge] "Dnipropetrovsk", 
   "Dnipropetrovsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Donetsk", 
   "Donetsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Dnipropetrovsk", 
   "Dnipropetrovsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Kharkiv", 
   "Kharkiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Dnipropetrovsk", 
   "Kherson" \[DirectedEdge] "Crimea", 
   "Dnipropetrovsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Poltava", 
   "Poltava" \[DirectedEdge] "Dnipropetrovsk", 
   "Poltava" \[DirectedEdge] "Kharkiv", 
   "Kharkiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Poltava", 
   "Poltava" \[DirectedEdge] "Sumy", "Sumy" \[DirectedEdge] "Poltava",
    "Poltava" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernihiv", 
   "Chernihiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Poltava", 
   "Chernihiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Kiev", 
   "Kiev" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernihiv", 
   "Kiev" \[DirectedEdge] "Cherkassy", 
   "Cherkassy" \[DirectedEdge] "Kiev", 
   "Cherkassy" \[DirectedEdge] "Kirovohrad", 
   "Kirovohrad" \[DirectedEdge] "Cherkassy", 
   "Kiev" \[DirectedEdge] "Poltava", "Poltava" \[DirectedEdge] "Kiev",
    "Poltava" \[DirectedEdge] "Cherkassy", 
   "Cherkassy" \[DirectedEdge] "Poltava", 
   "Kirovohrad" \[DirectedEdge] "Poltava", 
   "Poltava" \[DirectedEdge] "Kirovohrad", 
   "Kirovohrad" \[DirectedEdge] "Dnipropetrovsk", 
   "Dnipropetrovsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Kirovohrad", 
   "Kirovohrad" \[DirectedEdge] "Mykolayiv", 
   "Mykolayiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Kirovohrad", 
   "Mykolayiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Dnipropetrovsk", 
   "Dnipropetrovsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Mykolayiv", 
   "Mykolayiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Kherson", 
   "Kherson" \[DirectedEdge] "Mykolayiv", 
   "Mykolayiv" \[DirectedEdge] "Odessa", 
   "Odessa" \[DirectedEdge] "Mykolayiv", 
   "Odessa" \[DirectedEdge] "Kirovohrad", 
   "Kirovohrad" \[DirectedEdge] "Odessa", 
   "Odessa" \[DirectedEdge] "Vinnytsia", 
   "Vinnytsia" \[DirectedEdge] "Odessa", 
   "Vinnytsia" \[DirectedEdge] "Kirovohrad", 
   "Kirovohrad" \[DirectedEdge] "Vinnytsia", 
   "Vinnytsia" \[DirectedEdge] "Cherkassy", 
   "Cherkassy" \[DirectedEdge] "Vinnytsia", 
   "Vinnytsia" \[DirectedEdge] "Kiev", 
   "Kiev" \[DirectedEdge] "Vinnytsia", 
   "Vinnytsia" \[DirectedEdge] "Zhytomyr", 
   "Zhytomyr" \[DirectedEdge] "Vinnytsia", 
   "Zhytomyr" \[DirectedEdge] "Kiev", 
   "Kiev" \[DirectedEdge] "Zhytomyr", 
   "Vinnytsia" \[DirectedEdge] "Khmelnytsky", 
   "Khmelnytsky" \[DirectedEdge] "Vinnytsia", 
   "Khmelnytsky" \[DirectedEdge] "Zhytomyr", 
   "Zhytomyr" \[DirectedEdge] "Khmelnytsky", 
   "Khmelnytsky" \[DirectedEdge] "Rivne", 
   "Rivne" \[DirectedEdge] "Khmelnytsky", 
   "Rivne" \[DirectedEdge] "Zhytomyr", 
   "Zhytomyr" \[DirectedEdge] "Rivne", 
   "Vinnytsia" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernivtsi", 
   "Chernivtsi" \[DirectedEdge] "Vinnytsia", 
   "Chernivtsi" \[DirectedEdge] "Khmelnytsky", 
   "Khmelnytsky" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernivtsi", 
   "Chernivtsi" \[DirectedEdge] "Ternopil", 
   "Ternopil" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernivtsi", 
   "Ternopil" \[DirectedEdge] "Khmelnytsky", 
   "Khmelnytsky" \[DirectedEdge] "Ternopil", 
   "Ternopil" \[DirectedEdge] "Rivne", 
   "Rivne" \[DirectedEdge] "Ternopil", 
   "Rivne" \[DirectedEdge] "Lutsk", "Lutsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Rivne", 
   "Lutsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Lviv", "Lviv" \[DirectedEdge] "Lutsk", 
   "Lviv" \[DirectedEdge] "Ternopil", 
   "Ternopil" \[DirectedEdge] "Lviv", 
   "Lviv" \[DirectedEdge] "Ivano-Frankivsk", 
   "Ivano-Frankivsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Lviv", 
   "Ivano-Frankivsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Ternopil", 
   "Ternopil" \[DirectedEdge] "Ivano-Frankivsk", 
   "Ivano-Frankivsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Chernivtsi", 
   "Chernivtsi" \[DirectedEdge] "Ivano-Frankivsk", 
   "Ivano-Frankivsk" \[DirectedEdge] "Uzhgorod", 
   "Uzhgorod" \[DirectedEdge] "Ivano-Frankivsk", 
   "Uzhgorod" \[DirectedEdge] "Lviv", 
   "Lviv" \[DirectedEdge] "Uzhgorod"}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImagePadding -> 10]
```

Which produces a graph.

Then,

```
trans = Transpose[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]];

Total[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]];

Position[Total[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]], 0] // Flatten;

input = Table[0, {l, 1, 27}]; (input[[#]] = 1) & /@    Position[Total[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]], 0] // Flatten; input
```

Which gives

```
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Then

```
grr = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{0, 0}]}]; grg = Graphics[{Green, PointSize[0.05], Point[{0, 0}]}];

AdjacencyGraph[Transpose[trans], ImageSize -> Medium,   VertexStyle -> Table[i -> If[input[[i]] == 1, Red, Green], {i, 1, 27}]]
```

Which doesn't give me the graph I want, which should be of Russia with a red light and the rest with green. I just get some more code:

> AdjacencyGraph[Automatic, {{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1,     0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
>       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>       1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
>       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>       1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,     1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,     0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
>       0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0,
>       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,     0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}}, ImageSize -> Medium,
>   VertexStyle -> {1 -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 2 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     3
>   -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 4 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     5 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 6 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     7 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 8 ->
>   RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     9 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 10 -> RGBColor[0, 1,
>   0],     11 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 12 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     13 ->
>   RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 14 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     15 -> RGBColor[0, 1,
>   0], 16 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     17 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 18 ->
>   RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     19 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 20 -> RGBColor[0, 1,
>   0],     21 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 22 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     23 ->
>   RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 24 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     25 -> RGBColor[0, 1,
>   0], 26 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0],     27 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}]

Comment: Are you doing research on Ukraine?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create a dynamical model for the onset of war. My main point of focus is on the Ukraine situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Graph` and friends don't handle the case where `VertexStyle` has more entries than there are vertices. For some reason, you're using 27 as the upper limit of your `Table`s when defining `input` and iterating through `input` when providing `VertexStyle`, but you only have **26** vertices.

The best way to avoid these kinds of problems is to avoid indexing into graphs at all, by treating lists holistically with functional and rule-based programming. For instance:

```
styles =
  With[{totals = Total[Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[graph]]]},
   Thread[Range@Length@totals -> (
      totals /. {0 -> Red, n_?Positive -> Green})]];

AdjacencyGraph[Transpose[trans], ImageSize -> Medium, 
 VertexStyle -> styles]
```

This should do what you want.